# Can c# know the type of an object when it's value is null?

Tags: c#

While making some validation, I can across this situation

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if(!(value is IFileUploadInfo) && !(value is IEnumerable<IFileUploadInfo>))
        throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot use {nameof(FileValidationAttribute)} in a property that isn't of type {nameof(IFileUploadInfo)} or {nameof(IEnumerable<IFileUploadInfo>)}");

    // rest ...
}
```

Where I need to test if a `object` is of the type that I want, but if `value` is `null`, will c# know the type of that object even when it's `null`?

Comment: Do you mean the type of the variable passed to the method, because `null` technically has it's own type.

Comment: Honestly based on the type checking it might make sense to create overloads of this method for each type you expect it to handle.

Comment: For what it's worth *"the type of an object when it's value is null"* isn't really what you are asking.  Instances of reference types don't really have a *value* and are never *null*.  Reference-typed *variables*, however can be null.  Now, nullable value-typed instances can have the value *null*, but I don't think this is what you are asking about

Comment: Did you just try to see if C# does it? Isn't that quicker than asking a question here?

Comment: I can agree that this question isn't very clear and that I could have test that my self, sorry for that but thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't obtain type information from `null` with type check.

```
MyClass mc = null;
object obj = mc;
Console.WriteLine(obj is MyClass); // prints "False"
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) are clear about it:

> The `is` expression is true if expr isn't null, and ...

Comment: How saying that there is no solution maybe a solution when solutions were found?

Comment: @OlivierRogier first of all I don't state that the issue can't be worked around, my statement is about  extracting information from null with type check, the proposed solution does not extract information from `null` with type check. More over it will work opposite of desired in some cases (for obvious reasons), for example `var mc = new MyClass(); object obj = mc; IsValid(obj);` will end with `typeof(object)` for `typeof(T)` inside of `IsValid<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Passing with `object` in erases what the type was at compile time. Hence you have to do some pattern matching or casting to get it back out. Hence, `null` doesn't carry any type information with it.

You could make the method generic and then you could get what the type was.

```
public override bool IsValid<T>(T value)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    ... 
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you go this path, then calling `IsValid(null)` will result in a compile error.  If you call it as `MyType someVar = null; IsValid(someVar)` or `IsValid<MyType>(null);` should work.